# Query MongoDb with Spring Data without specifying a POJO?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-jpa

I am writing a simple test harness to run externally from an application to check correct documents are being sent into my mongo db. All I need to do is check the document counts of a few collections. Is there a way of doing this in Spring Data without specifying POJOs? As I don't require any data to actually be mapped.

Comment: `org.bson.Document` class. Its defined in the MongoDB Java Driver APIs.

Comment: That said, document counts can also be stored as a `Long` or `long`.